# Target and dependency are both the same

Tags: makefile

I'm write the following makefile:

```
TARGET=fmake
TARGET2=test_second
f:f
    echo Some text
clean:
    rm -f fmake test_second
CC=$(VAR2)
VAR2=gcc
```

After make command I have:

```
make: Circular f <- f dependency dropped.
echo Some text
Some text
```

What does mean `make: Circular f <- f dependency dropped.` Is it true that

```
f:f
    echo Some text
```

just equivalent to

```
f:
    echo Some text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true that `f: f` is the same as `f:`.  The latter defines a target `f` which doesn't depend on any other files.  The former defines a target `f` which depends on a file `f` (the same file).

This is an impossible situation, because `f` cannot be updated before itself.  Before `f` can be built make will try to build its prerequisites, which are `f`.  But before the prerequisite `f` can be built make must build *its* prerequisite, which is `f`.  And before that can be built make must build *its* prerequisite which is also `f`.  Etc. forever and ever.

There are different things make *could* do when it finds this impossible situation.  It could, for example, just fail with an error code.

But instead what make chooses to do is drop the prerequisite to avoid the recursion.  That's what the warning message you see means.

So *in effect* although they are not the same thing, make does end up *treating* `f:f` as if it were just `f`.